# How to open ClockworkMod's .tar.a archives?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

To open the TAR archive on my PC, I have to rename the `.tar.a` to `.tar`, otherwise my archive manager will say "Archive type unsupported" or similar.

Why do they do that, and how to open these archives in a proper way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does this in order to break up large `.tar` files into chunks of 1000000000 bytes (or 1 [GB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte)):

```
-rwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          0 2014-03-19 14:31 data.ext4.tar
-rwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r 1000000000 2014-03-19 14:33 data.ext4.tar.a
-rwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r 1000000000 2014-03-19 14:36 data.ext4.tar.b
-rwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r 1000000000 2014-03-19 14:38 data.ext4.tar.c
-rwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r  135127040 2014-03-19 14:38 data.ext4.tar.d
```

Even if the resulting file is under the 1000000000-byte split limit, the `.a` file will still be generated:

```
-rwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r         0 2014-03-19 14:29 system.ext4.tar
-rwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r 484504064 2014-03-19 14:30 system.ext4.tar.a
```

You can combine these split files back together using the following syntax:

On Windows: `copy /b finelame* filename` E.g. `copy /b data.ext4.tar* data.ext4.tar`
On Linux: `cat filename* > filename` E.g. `cat data.ext4.tar* > data.ext4.tar`

Comment: Thanks, good answer but why is .tar always zero?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, I'd have to look into CWM code. It's probably a placeholder for the original file name.

Comment: You sir disearve every single internet prizes and nominations. You have just saved my life (and my contacts list) for I didn't know how to put those .a .b .c and the zero-ed rar file together. For the question about the 0kb .rar, during the cmd (which I recomend runing trough the folder using SHIFT+right click > open command window here) every chunk of tar file will be copied towards the zero-ed rar file.
Thanks again bud.